# What side should a django 'many-to-many' relationship reside on

Tags: python, django, django-models

Lets say I have a recipe website with two basic models, 'User' and 'Recipe'

```
class User(models.Model):
    username= models.CharField()
    email = models.CharField()

class Recipe(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    description = models.CharField()
```

I would like to add the functionality so that users can 'favorite' a recipe.

In this case, I need to use a many-to-many relationship. My question is, how do I decide which model to add the relationship to?

For example, each user could have a list of 'favorite' recipes:

```
class User(models.Model):
    favorites = models.ManyToManyField(Recipe)
```

Alternatively, each recipe could have a list of users who Favorited the recipe:

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    user_favorites = models.ManyToManyField(User)
```

What is considered the best practice? Is either one better for query performance?

Comment: It makes absolutely no difference, just choose whatever feels right.

Comment: There is no "side" in terms of RDBMS as it will always create an intermediary table. It is just a way of declaring it in the models, so feel free to choose the one that makes more sense to you.

Comment: I wouldn't quite agree about, "absolutely no difference". Please see my answer and correct me if I'm wrong! @knbk :)

Answer (score 14):

It makes no difference from the database point of view, as pointed out in the comments.

But I have had two arguments where it did matter to me.

- First (maybe less important), the built-in admin treats the two models differently by default. The model on which you define the relationship gets a widget for choosing the related objects. And a '+' for conveniently adding new objects of the related type.
- secondly, you have to import one of the models in the file of the other one, if they are in different files. This matters if you want to write a reusable app that does not depend on anything outside. It mattered to me also because:
  I once (well, not just once actually :)) broke my app/database/etc such, that I decided to start a new project and copy the code there. In this case you have to comment out some `settings.INSTALLED_APPS` to test step for step that everything works. Here it is important not to have circular includes (to include a commented-out app raises an error). So I try to import the "most basic" into the others, and not the other way round.

This not a simple answer to your question, but two points which I consider. Maybe some more experienced users can correct me if it's wrong in some sense.